# Can't parse date from concatenated string

Tags: kql

I am about to lose my mind with something so apparently simple. I want to parse a string into a datetime but it keeps returning null.

If I do `todatetime(strcat(2020,"-11-7"))` it returns null.
And if I do `todatetime("2020-11-7")` it works.
I compared both strings and they are equal.

This is the code that I am testing:

```
let dateStr = strcat(2020,"-11-7");
let dateStr2 = "2020-11-7";
print dateStr == dateStr2 // True
print todatetime(dateStr) == todatetime(dateStr2) // False
```

Any idea why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: As far as I can tell you're not doing anything wrong. This seems to me like a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to convert `strcat(2020,"-11-7")` to `datetime` fails because the string that is created is not a supported datetime format. Please see the list of supported formats in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime#supported-formats).

However, if you try to convert `strcat(2020,"-11-07")` (note the `07` instead of just `7`), then it will produce the desired result.

Converting `"2020-11-7"` to `datetime` does work (like you noticed) even though this is not a supported format, for backward compatibility (but it's recommended to refrain from using unsupported formats, in any case).

Comment: I have confirmed this works and solves my issue, but I am still fazed by the fact that two strings are equal and yet their conversion to datetime is not the same. Does kql make a distinction in the back on how the string was created to provide a different output with the same string?

Comment: String literals (e.g. `"2020-11-7"`) and string expressions (e.g. `strcat(2020,"-11-7")`) are parsed by different libraries. Therefore, you should strive to have the literals and expressions comply with the supported formats (which both libraries know to parse): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime#supported-formats

Comment: The documentation in the link explains the formats supported by datetime literals, which receive a value that is not a string since is not enclosed in quotes (e.g. `datetime(2020-11-07)`), and for parsing from strings (e.g. `todatetime("2020-11-07")`). But there is never a distinction between string literals and string expressions and how it can affect the parsing. I tried googling for those terms, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: The documentation purposely doesn't differentiate between string literals and string expressions. As long as you provide strings in the supported format, they will be parsed regardless of whether they are literals or expressions. The string `"2020-11-7"` does not comply with any of the supported formats, which is why it works in some cases, and doesn't work in some other cases.