# KQL Azure Log Analytics can't parse datetime from regex expression

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-data-explorer, kql, date-conversion

Given a table with columns "RawData" and "_ResourceId", which is the Azure ARM ID, I want to parse a string from a server log file like:

```
"09:08:52,198 INFO [web.org.perfmon4j.extras.jbossweb7.P....."
```

and pull parts of the string into my custom table for later analysis.

The Kusto KQL query in the Azure Log Analytics editor:

```
suggest_CL
| project dt = todatetime(extract("^([\\:0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)", 1, 
       "09:08:52,198 INFO [web.org.perfmon4j.extras.jbossweb7.P")),
dtstr = extract("^([\\:0-9]+)\\,([0-9]+)", 1, 
        "09:08:52,198 INFO [web.org.perfmon4j.extras.jbossweb7.P"),
statictimestr = "09:09:52",
statictime = todatetime("09:09:52"),
 _ResourceId, RawData
```

where `suggest_CL` is the Custom Table

The `dtstr` column shows that the regex works and returns the correct time value.

I include some test strings:

```
statictimestr = "09:09:52",
```

This is a simple time only string. The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime) says it will use today's date if the date is not included.

```
statictime = todatetime("09:09:52"),
```

This is the above string converted to `datetime`

The output is

| dt [UTC] | dtstr | statictimestr | statictime [UTC] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 09:08:52 | 09:09:52 | 2023-06-15T09:09:52Z |

and the `dt` column is empty, implying that the `todatetime(...)` expression evaluated to null. The `statictime` column is noted as `[UTC]`, so the parsing of the time-only expression was successful for the string literal. Outputting `isnull(todatetime(...))` shows `true`.

The output of the `extract(regex)` expression is NOT parsed correctly.

Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65853355/4512803) answers by saying the format is incorrect. There seems to be more problem here than that, like a bug handling function expressions as an argument to `todatetime()`. That possibility was expressed in the other question.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`todatetime()` has different implementations for constant values and for calculated values - not the same set of formats is supported in both. The official set of supported formats (for both) is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime#supported-formats).

This is why for an unsupported format, it may work for you when you provide a constant value, but may not otherwise.

For unsuppported formats, one thing you could try is to parse the separate date parts using the [`parse` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator), then use [the `make_datetime()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-datetimefunction) to create a datetime value out of them.

For example:

```
print input = "09:08:52,198 INFO [web.org.perfmon4j.extras.jbossweb7.P....."
| parse input with hours:int ":" minutes:int ":" seconds:double "," *
| extend dt = make_datetime(datetime_part("Year", now()), datetime_part("Month", now()), datetime_part("Day", now()), hours, minutes, seconds)
```